# Adding HTTP headers and parameters in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift4

How can I send a HTTP Get Request with the following parameters in Swift4 without using any external library?

```
URL: "https://api.newsapi.aylien.com/api/v1/stories"
Parameters = ["categories.confident": "true", "source.name" : "The New York Times", "cluster" : "false", "cluster.algorithm" : "lingo", "sort_by" : "published_at", "sort_direction" : "desc", "cursor" : "*", "per_page" : "10"]
Headers = ["X-AYLIEN-NewsAPI-Application-ID": "App-ID-Here", "X-AYLIEN-NewsAPI-Application-Key": "App-Key-Here"]
```

Comment: The same way you do in Swift 3. Use `URLRequest` and `URLSession`.

Comment: How do I add parameters and headers in a URLRequest?

Comment: This isn't a hard problem. You're asking how to do the most basic of functionality. Read the documentation.

Comment: Give it a try, and come back with a specific question. At the moment this question reads like a requirement that you want somebody to give you tho code for.

Answer (score 13):

You can use like this :

```
let urlString = "https://api.newsapi.aylien.com/api/v1/stories"
let parameters = ["categories.confident": "true", "source.name" : "The New York Times", "cluster" : "false", "cluster.algorithm" : "lingo", "sort_by" : "published_at", "sort_direction" : "desc", "cursor" : "*", "per_page" : "10"]
let headers = ["X-AYLIEN-NewsAPI-Application-ID": "App-ID-Here", "X-AYLIEN-NewsAPI-Application-Key": "App-Key-Here"]

var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: urlString)

var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()
for (key, value) in parameters {
    queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
}

urlComponents?.queryItems = queryItems

var request = URLRequest(url: (urlComponents?.url)!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

for (key, value) in headers {
    request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
}

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    print(response)
}
task.resume()
```